# How to remove/change "Estimated Changes" in Phantom app?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, nft, phantom

I need to not show Estimated Changes before sending a transaction, is there any way to do this? Or even change the parameters that are shown there. When I send tokens to myself. I have a hunch that it has something to do with `skipPreflight` or `simulateTransaction(transaction, config?)`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something apps are able to configure, and wallets are free to display whatever they like. This is a security feature for users. Usually the estimated changes are based on transaction simulation, but wallets sometimes have their own extra checks or third party security services involved too.

Comment: Go it. So how to use ' simulateTransaction ' for example?

Comment: That's just an RPC method, eg see https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#simulateTransaction for web3js docs, https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/simulatetransaction for full RPC docs